# Datasheet style forms

Tags: form, datasheet

Is there any way to do a datasheet type view for a form. I'd like to be able to allow people to enter multiple list items at once without giving them access to see the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create a Data View Web Part
2. Select the Data Source
3. Select the fields you want the user to be able to modify
4. On Data Source tab, select

   4.1 "Select Selected Fields as..."

   4.2 "Multiple Item Form"

You should use filter to restrict how much you want to show from the list.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that I know of that lets you directly do that.  I would say you have two approaches.  You can use a datasheet view on the list and if you don't want them to see all items create the default view of 'Assigned To' = [Me], so they only see their own items.

Another option would be to use InfoPath and create a form and set the action on submit to clear the form and stay on the same page.  This way they wouldn't even see the list, it would just be a form that they could easily fill out multiple times.